# How to get a list of top 5 links from a google search?

Tags: java

I need a list of top 5 links obtained from a user query about a partiuclar subject.Is there any way by which I can do this ? How can I fetch top 5 links of a google search ?
Is there any API available for it ?Some demo examples will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doing so, Wont google sue you? :-/

Comment: I tried searching on Internet about it but all my efforts were useless,in short won't abled to solve it :(

Comment: Doesn't look like there is an official API for non-custom searches: https://code.google.com/more/#google-search

Answer (score 3):

Google does provide an [API for search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview). You have to:

1. Get a/use your Google account
2. [Sign up for an API key](http://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=customsearch) (sadly, they only allow 100 searches a day for free)
3. Have a look at their [Java samples](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#CustomSearch_API) for custom search, [here](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/apis/customsearch/v1/index.html).

Comment: Can you tell me how to install Google custom Search in netbeans in windows 7 ? I'm facing difficulty in it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JSoup, its a Java HTML Parser.

I suggest learning about DOM, will make your life much easier. http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation